# Screen tears with MSI GE72 2QD Apache Pro dual booting Linux with windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, apache2, msi

I have been losing my mind and sleep for the past 4 days. I used Ubuntu to run linux alongside windows. (That was a huge pain in the ass.) Now I am getting a bunch of screen tears. I have tried loads of tutorials but nothing has worked, or maybe I am doing something wrong. I am new to linux, and potato smart when it comes to computers, but I am trying to learn. Has anyone been able to solve this issue running the GTX 960M? Any help is really appreciated. I tried other options and tutorials. But I feel like I am running out of options to get this to work correctly for my specific model.

This also happens when I plug in two other Asus monitors. Can anyone please help me. I have tried 6 or 7 different ways to try and get this to work. My computer will also freeze and crash sometimes if I have nvidia as my main card.

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary drivers? (Dash > Additional Drivers)

Comment: Yes. I believe so. The most recent proprietary driver is 352.63 from nvidia-352. Then I have about 6 open source drivers. One being the Nouveau, but I believe that one is the issue or just isn't compatible. The others are all nvidia open source binary drivers. version 352.63 from nvidia-352, 352.79-from nvidia-352, version 355.11 from nvidia-355, version 358.16 from nvidia-358, and version 361.18 from nvidia-361.

Comment: Those are all recognized in ubuntu's software and updates additional Drivers tab.

Answer (score 0):

1. Blacklist nouveau in grub (add nouveau.blacklist=1 to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable in /etc/default/grub then do sudo update-grub)
2. install nvidia Drivers (latest) using apt
3. install microcode drivers from additional drivers
4. add i915.modeset=1 to grub (similar to step 1)

do all steps then only restart computer, else you might face a login loop.
If you face a login loop, set grub parameters while booting (Press E on grub menu then add parameters to the linux line then F10 to boot)

5. Use nvidia drivers when using multiple monitors, and use intel graphics when using single monitor to save battery. this settings can be done in nvidia control panel.